# dual boot ubuntu 14 and windows 7 - was working, now: windows starts, goes black, and hangs

Tags: windows-7, boot

dual boot was working fine for months.  I don't know what happened, now:  grub shows ubuntu and win7, when i choose win7 win starts, hangs at startup progress bar and goes black.  nothing.

I tried boot repair.  Said it solved it.  Created another win7 load entry on other partition but neither of them works.

Any ideas?  thanks.  If I can't fix the dual boot, I'd be happy to get win7 to load, that's my working os.

Comment: Here is the boot repair link:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/117261191

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Windows 7 install or recovery DVD/USB to repair Windows booting first - use "StartUp Repair" (run it three times with rebooting after each run).

BootRepair cannot always solve Windows 7 boot problems.

Then you can reinstall GRUB using Ubuntu live DVD/USB if you want GRUB to control the dual-boot.

Alternatively you can leave Windows boot manager (after repairing) to control the dual-boot and create a boot sector loader for Ubuntu in Windows Boot Configuration - see [Dual-boot Windows 7 and Linux](http://www.boyans.net/DualBootWindows7andLinuxOrUnix.html) for details.